# SQL Server with special character datas

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have a datas exported from **mysql** because I'm using now **SQL Server 2014**. Now the records that are stored are ok. The problem now is when I try to insert a new record (via PHP code) when I tried to insert a record with a special character let's say `ñ` it stores these `Ã±`, but in retreiving it returns `ñ`. Here are the specs that I'm using:

> CentOS Linux 6.3
>   Apache 2.2.15
>   PHP 5.3.3
>   SQL Server 2014
>   CodeIgniter 2.2.0

I know the solution would be `utf8_decode()` but I'm looking for another solution that would work globally.

Can you give me any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set `Collation` to `utf8_general_ci` in table. That is work for you.